# Is it possible to do "if file exists then append, else create new file" shorter than this

Tags: php

I have the following code but I'm trying to shorten it about one or two lines, as I believe the `if` is unnecessary. Is there any way the code below can shortened to a singular line?

```
 if(file_exists($myFile))
    {
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
        fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
    }
    else
    {
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
    }
```

Comment: What's the reason for shortening it?

Comment: The [PHP Manual for `fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) clearly state `a`: *"Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it."* - so what is the question?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
if (file_exists($myFile)) {
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
  fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
} else {
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
  fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

==

```
if (file_exists($myFile)) {
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
} else {
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
} 
fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
fclose($fh);
```

==

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, (file_exists($myFile)) ? 'a' : 'w');
fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
fclose($fh);
```

== (because `a` checks if the file exists and creates it if not)

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
fclose($fh);
```

==

```
file_put_contents($myFile, $message."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

...of course, [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) is only better if it is the only write you perform on a given handle. If you have any later calls to `fwrite()` on the same file handle, you're better going with @Pekka's answer.

Answer (score 17):

Umm... why?  `a` already does what you need out of the box.

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Comment: Good for log. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

```
$method = (file_exists($myFile)) ? 'a' : 'w';
$fh = fopen($myFile,$method);
fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

[fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). mode `a` all you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
$fh = (file_exists($myFile)) ? fopen($myFile,'a') : fopen($myFile,'w');
fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$fh = file_exists($myFile) ? fopen($myFile, 'a') : fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
```

Comment: But why? What sense does the check make in the first place?

Comment: Your reply makes more sense :)

Answer (score 1):

The append mode already does just what you describe. From the PHP manual page for [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen):

> 'a': Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the php manual this should be enough. See the [description of "a"](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
fopen($myFile, "a");
fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
```

Comment: Missing `;` after `fopen($myFile, "a")`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `a` (append) mode does that already... append if exists, else create new

```
fopen($myFile, "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$method = (file_exists($myFile)) ? 'a' : 'w';

$fh = fopen($myFile,$method);

fwrite($fh, $message."\n");
```

Isn't it $myFile contains absolute/relative path..?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [*SPL* / Standard PHP Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php):

```
# addfile.php
$file = new \SplFileObject( __DIR__.'/foo.txt', 'a' );
var_dump( file_exists( $file->getFilename() ) );

$ php addfile.php
bool(true)
```